# How do I shut off scrolling on the Instagram in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, instagram

I've created a web game, and for some reason Instagram Stories swipe ups adds padding to the bottom of the game. It operates fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (both mobile and desktop), and fine on Android's Instagram in-app browser - just not iOS. How do I force no scroll on the site?

I have tried overflow: hidden and:

```js
 document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

But no luck.